# Include script in infinite scroll Wordpress Posts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, infinite-scroll

We are currently using Ajax infinite scroll for blog posts. But we wanted to included scripts (javascript) on every blogposts. Everything works fine except the script only show once at the very top portion of the blogpost.

here is the snippet for the singles.php loop which has been modified for Ajax infinite scroll standards:

```html
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if (et_get_option('divi_integration_single_top') <> '' && et_get_option('divi_integrate_singletop_enable') == 'on') echo(et_get_option('divi_integration_single_top')); ?>
    <?php
    echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more cache="true" cache_id="2869844236" cta="true" cta_position="after:1" css_classes="call-to-actions call-to-actions-js" images_loaded="true" post_type="post" repeater="default" previous_post="true" previous_post_id="'. get_the_ID() .'" posts_per_page="1" button_label="Previous Post"]');
    ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

and here is the snippet for the repeater template which include a simple script code.

```html
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'et_pb_post' ); ?>>
  <script>
    document.write("This text is displayed using a simple javascript.");
  </script>
  <div class="et_post_meta_wrapper">
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('hero', array('alt' => get_the_title())); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="entry-content">
    <?php
    do_action( 'et_before_content' );

    the_content();

    wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'Divi' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) );
    ?>
  </div>
</article>
```

Not sure why the script only show once. when I've placed it on the top of the title of each blogposts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.write()` will make an indirect call to `document.open()` to open the new output stream when your ajax request the repeater template. Next time you scroll more the `write()` method does not works because the previous output stream is currently open. You should close the stream.

You can try this way:

```
document.open();
document.write("This text is displayed using a simple javascript.");
document.close();
```

document.write() is a bad practice for production. You should only use it for testing.

Better solution:

```
<p id="output"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "This text is displayed using a simple javascript.";
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

To display text every time once the ajax request is done we will need a unique id to append text to the element.

In my above suggestion

id must be unique to repeat the text from JavaScript.

**Solution:**

We will use WordPress for the little help. WordPress has unique ids for all the post you create.

`the_ID();` method inside WordPress While loop returns the post id. So append the same id in our `P` element and append our text by getting the element by its new id.

```
<p id="output-<?php the_ID(); ?>"></p>

<script>
  var idname = document.getElementById("output-<?php the_ID(); ?>");
  idname.innerHTML = "This text is displayed using a simple javascript.";
</script>
```

This will append the text in every post.

Comment: Thanks, for this. I will surely apply your advice.
but how do I also make it repeat within the loop of every posts?

Comment: I think your repeater template goes inside WordPress while loop so, It should repeat unless you have post or do ajax request.

Comment: The Repeater template works fine...it loops all/display all posts as intended. my problem is the script I've included inside the repeater template. most specifically above the blog post title. Instead of showing on every blogposts, it only shows up on the 1st blog post.

Comment: Did you tried the above suggestion? As I have explained above how write() method works (only once if not open / close the stream properly), you should hard code some text or use innerHTML and test the scroll.

Comment: yes my new repeater template is now looking like this..
https://www.screencast.com/t/LDkxZiAAUlEL

but it still display the script once on the very 1st blogpost instead of every blogpost

Comment: @BryanReas check the edit section in my answer. It will solve your problem and its a tested method.

Comment: thank you...that really solved the simple problem :)